# inserting style into javascript based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, gridjs

I'm using grid.js to put some data into the table.

In one column I have an icon and I want it to change color based on a condition I pass, as shown below.

`style='color: " + cell.amount ? + " 'green' " : " 'red' '`

Specifically I want this to be green when amount is full, red otherwise.

I'm having a problem; I notice that **NaN** is shown in the column.

Can anyone kindly help me?

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [
      { 
        name: 'Name',
        formatter: (cell) => html(`<b style='color: " + cell.amount ? + " 'green' " : " 'red' '>${cell}</b>`)
      },
      'Email',
      { 
        name: 'Actions',
        formatter: (_, row) => html(`<a href='mailto:${row.cells[1].data}'>Email</a>`)
      },
   ],
  data: Array(5).fill().map(x => [
    faker.name.findName(),
    faker.internet.email(),
    null
  ])
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `+` after `?`

Comment: Is that HTML or JS? It looks like you're trying to put JavaScript inside the HTML attribute. That doesn't work.

Comment: It needs to be JavaScript: `element.style.color = employee.amount ? 'green' : 'red'`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar Updated answer with an example. Please remove the negative answer from me

Comment: `<b style='color: " + cell.amount ? + " 'green' " : " 'red' '>${cell}</b>` your single and double quotes seem to be mismatched. `cell.amount...`is going to be read as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra quotes that aren't needed.

And since you're using a template literal, you substitute into it with `${...}`, not concatenation.

```
formatter: (cell) => html(`<b style='color: ${cell.amount ? "green" : "red"}'>${cell}</b>`)
```